# SQL prepared statement with different LIMIT values per group

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having a problem with limiting selected records in a query. What I'd like to do is Limit groups of records based off a calculated field per group. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
dealer_cap - Count( DynamicList_Used.dealer_id ) AS LeftToDial

INTO @Limit

FROM DynamicList_Used
INNER JOIN DealerCap 
ON DynamicList_Used.dealer_id = DealerCap.dealer_id 

WHERE
(
(
( DynamicList_Used.list_name ) = "OverDue"
OR ( DynamicList_Used.list_name ) = "SoonDue" 
OR ( DynamicList_Used.list_name ) = "Expired" 
OR ( DynamicList_Used.list_name ) = "Customer" 
) 
AND ( ( DynamicList_Used.creation_date ) BETWEEN '2017-09-21' AND '2017-
10-20' ) 
)

GROUP BY
DealerCap.dealer_id,
DealerCap.Program

HAVING
( ( ( DealerCap.Program ) = "National" ) );



PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM DynamicList_Usable GROUP BY dealer_id, lead_id LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @Limit;
```

This returns '1172 - Result consisted of more than one row'. I've tested the first Select statement on it's own and I know it is returning the values I am expecting to see, it's just that the prepared statement isn't able to accept more than one value.

My question is how can I get this working with multiple values, matching dealer_id and using the limit produced from the select into statement per dealer_id matched. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Tell us why you need a `GROUP BY`.  Tell us why the `HAVING` could not be added to the `WHERE`.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: GROUP BY in the first statement is to get the LIMIT value per grouped value. GROUP BY in the second statement was to try and return the LIMIT value in each group which didn't work. The HAVING statement could be rolled into the WHERE statement, not sure why it was setup that way originally.

Comment: If you need "top-n", see [groupwise-max].

Comment: You are trying to get multiple values of a group by query into a single @Limit? What is "consuming" the result of your prepared statement? (*I suspect you would be better of doing there whatever that is.*)